# How to change DFS time complexity O(V^2) to O(V+E) or O(V+2E) for undirectional graphs

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, graph-algorithm

Trying to improve on my algorithms I tried to write DFS code in O(V+2E) time complexity but it seems like I ended up with O(V^2). Please help me out with code fix. I can use recursive process by moving one of the while loops into a subroutine. Is that the only way to fix it or we can do something else to fix it.

```
package com.dfs;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Stack;

public class MainMethod {

/**
 * @param args
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> nodesList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> list4 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> list5 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> list6 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(1);
    list1.add(2);
    list2.add(3);
    list2.add(2);
    list3.add(3);
    list4.add(4);
    list5.add(5);
    list5.add(1);
    list5.add(0);
    nodesList.add(list1);
    nodesList.add(list2);
    nodesList.add(list3);
    nodesList.add(list4);
    nodesList.add(list5);
    nodesList.add(list6);

    //List to check vertext has been visted or not
    List<List<Integer>> vertexVisitCheck = new ArrayList();
    Stack<List<Integer>> tobeExplored = new Stack<>();
    System.out.println(nodesList);
    int startnode = 0;
    tobeExplored.push(nodesList.get(startnode));
    System.out.println("Added to the Stack ===> "+nodesList.get(startnode));
    while(!tobeExplored.isEmpty())
    {
        List<Integer> nextVertex = tobeExplored.peek();;
            vertexVisitCheck.add(nextVertex);
            Iterator<Integer> iterator = nextVertex.iterator();
            int counter = nextVertex.size();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                int check =  iterator.next();
                if(!vertexVisitCheck.contains(nodesList.get(check)))
                {
                    tobeExplored.push(nodesList.get(check));
                    System.out.println("Added to the Stack ===> "+nodesList.get(check));
                    if(tobeExplored.peek().size()==0)
                    {
                        vertexVisitCheck.add(nodesList.get(check));
                        tobeExplored.pop();
                    }
                        break;
                }
                if(--counter==0)
                {
                    vertexVisitCheck.add(nodesList.get(check));
                    tobeExplored.pop();
                }       
          }
     }
 }
```

}